# Magento 2 optimize performance by separating static element and cache

Tags: magento2, cache, performance, file

I'm drafting the system diagram of my site. I'm planning to use multiple servers 4 apache servers, 2 db servers and 2 file server for performance enhancement.

As Magento has many cache files and media files. I decided to put media files into file servers for speed and easy management. But for cache files, I'm still thinking should I put them into file servers.

Anyone can give some suggestion? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and recommended way are use Redis as cache storage.

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html for more details